# PHP coding help for beginner

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have `$abc = "http://somewebsite.com/somefile.jpg"`. How do I show this URL in an input box so that the user can easily copy the link with a single click? Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want javascript, not php.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $abc; ?>" />`

Comment: I think what you need is a `copy to clipboard` kind of functionality. If so, it is not a foolproof method. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Standart input: `$input = "<input type='text' value='$abc' />"`

If you want `copy` it by click - you need swf/js. But you can look this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)** for such solution.

Comment: What about the JS part? No example for that?

Comment: JS solutions dont work good. So mostly flash objects are used for that.

Comment: flash is a dieing technology, and will not be natively supported in the near future, i would stay away from flash unless there is no other method of accomplishing your goals

Comment: @relentless I dont said it's better. But you are right, flash is `better` way coz it works in all browsers and in 100% cases. JS.. have many troubles with it and single solution for single browser. Read my link please and find out lot of new :)

Comment: @EyalAlsheich All are saying that flash dies (and i agree with that mostly).. but it still alive. And `HTML5`.. isnt good enough yet. Even Facebook denied `html5`-way of development and moves back to flash.

Comment: @relentless "Mark Zuckerberg: Our Biggest Mistake Was Betting Too Much On HTML5". Read this: [news post](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/11/mark-zuckerberg-our-biggest-mistake-with-mobile-was-betting-too-much-on-html5/)

Comment: He was referring to their mobile app. It's now done naively, not in Flash.

Comment: @relentless so dont say Flash is bad. This thecknology has great and wide field of use.

Answer (score 0):

The copying is mostly done in Flash, most browsers do not allow to access the clipboard from javascript for security reasons.
You will need to pass the data to be copied to Flash, and place it inside the clipboard from there on.

Maybe this can help you: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Answer (score 0):

You can put your URL in a input box like this before the page has rendered....

file.php

```
<?php
  $abc = "http://somewebsite.com/somefile.jpg";
?>
<input type="text" name="someURL" value="<?php echo $abc;?>" />
```

OR
file.php

```
<?php
  $abc = "http://somewebsite.com/somefile.jpg";
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"someURL\" value=\"".$abc."\" />";
?>
```

As for the copying - fiddly stuff